# Criar um loop para cada categoria de post

Tags: php, wordpress

Oi
Sou novo em programaçao e novo no desenvolvimento com  wordpress.

Estou tentando criar uma pagina de depoimentos, com custom post tipes atilizando de sub categorias. 
A idéia é ter 4 categorias de depoimentos. E ter um loop para cada categoria.
Para isso estou utilizando o accordion do bootstrap 4.
Então, quando o usuario clica em determinada categoria, é exibido o loop de post daquela categoria em questão.

Eu já consegui fazer o foreach para exibir o menu das 4 categorias.
Mas não estou conseguindo estruturar os lopps dentro de cada categoria.

Segue o código:

```
    <!-- Display the menu of categories, essa parte funciona OK -->
    <?php   
    $catList = get_categories(
    array(
    'child_of' => 103,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => '0'
    ) );
    ?>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <?php $c = 1 ?>
    <?php foreach($catList as $catItem) : ?>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="<?php echo $catItem->slug?>-tab">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $catItem->slug?>" aria-expanded="<?php echo ($c == 2)?'true':'false'; ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $catItem->slug?>">
    <?php echo $catItem->name?>
    </button>
    </h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php $c++ ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <!-- End of Display the menu of categories -->
```

O propblema é na hora de fazer os loops de cada categoria
Estou fazendo assim:

```
    <!-- Aqui o loop para cada categoria, Essa parte nao funciona  -->
    <?php $c = 1 ?>
    <?php foreach($catList as $catItem) : ?>
    <?php
    $argsPosts = array(
    'post_type' => 'depoimentos',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'cat' => $catItem->cat_ID
    ); 
    ?>

    <?php $bladeQuery = new WP_Query($argsPosts); ?><?php if($bladeQuery->have_posts()) : ?><?php while ($bladeQuery->have_posts()) : ?><?php $bladeQuery->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $catItem->slug?>" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="card-body">
    HEAR THE CONTENT OF EACH TESTIMONIALS
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?><?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?><!-- end query -->
    <?php $c++ ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Edite o template do seu custom post type via template.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/

Quando for exibir as categorias ao inves de utilizar um botão

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $catItem->slug?>" aria-expanded="<?php echo ($c == 2)?'true':'false'; ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $catItem->slug?>">
```

Use um link

```
<a class="btn btn-link" title="Home" href="/depoimentos/'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</a>
```

Caso você queria fazer algo assíncrono você vai ter que fazer algo tipo este post
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html